# Not understanding how docker build --secret is supposed to be used

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I can get the [example](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information) working that Docker provides and just about every blog is just a variation of it: just printing out the secret value in the build output.

Cool... but I need to get it into my app that is looking for it and failing to build because it doesn't exist. That much isn't clear to me and I've been unable to figure it out myself.

This is the project structure:

```
project-root/
  api/
    docker/
      Dockerfile
      mysecret.txt
    src/
      ...
    manage.py
```

This is the `Dockerfile` (the last three lines are probably the most relevant):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8-slim as python-base
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"


FROM python-base as builder-base
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        curl \
        build-essential

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.1.8
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python

WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml ./
RUN poetry install --no-dev


FROM python-base as development
ENV FASTAPI_ENV=development

COPY --from=builder-base $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH

COPY ./docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
RUN poetry install

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh $0 $@
CMD ["python", "src/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5000"]


FROM development AS test
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret export MYSECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/mysecret)
RUN coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' src/manage.py test src && coverage report
```

This is the command:

```
$ docker build -f docker/Dockerfile --no-cache --secret id=mysecret,src=docker/mysecret.txt --target=test --progress=plain .
```

The app itself is looking for:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['MYSECRET']
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['mysecret']
```

But it always fails at the last step of the `Dockerfile` saying it can't find the necessary env var, `MYSECRET` or `mysecret`, to run the app.

I've tried numerous things to resolve the issue and figure out how to appropriately get the secret into the app:

- Adding a `export MYSECRET` step to hopefully add it as env var: `printenv` shows nothing in the `docker run -it <image> bash`.
- Finding the value in `/run/secrets/mysecret` in the `docker run -it <image> bash` which doesn't exist (as it shouldn't).

It just seems like by the time it gets to the `RUN coverage ...` the value is no longer available.

So what do I need to do here to get `docker build --secret` working properly with my `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short answer

Could you try to combine 2 `RUN coverage` with `RUN --mount ...` ?

I think it will be something like that :

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret \
  export MYSECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/mysecret) \
  && coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' src/manage.py test src \
  && coverage report
```

### Detail

This `--secret` flag persists only in one docker layer.

> The final image built will not have the secret file

Documentation :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypesecret

Blog about it:

https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-buildkit/

each `RUN` creates one intermediate layer.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

So, according to my understanding,

`RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret export MYSECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/mysecret)`

will not persist both in your final image and in your last `RUN`.

### EDIT 1

RUN is executed by `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash` so you have to instanciate `MYSECRET` and export it in 2 steps :

> /bin/sh -c [your RUN instructions]

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret \
    MYSECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/mysecret) \
    && export MYSECRET \
    && coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' src/manage.py test src \
    && coverage report
```

Here is my working example :

- test.py

  > print MYSECRET value

  ```py
  import os

  print(os.environ["MYSECRET"])
  ```
- mysecret.txt

  > contains MYSECRET value

  ```
  Hello
  ```
- Dockerfile

  > based on python:3.9 image

  ```
  FROM python:3.9

  COPY test.py /tmp/test.py

  RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret \
    MYSECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/mysecret) \
    && export MYSECRET \
    && python /tmp/test.py
  ```
- Build output

  ```bash
  ...
  #7 [3/3] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret     MYSECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/mysecret)     && export MYSECRET     && python /tmp/test.py
  #7 sha256:f0134fcb389100e7094a47f437f8630e67da83447daaf617756c1d8432163bae
  #7 0.374 Hello
  #7 DONE 0.4s
  ...
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately, combining them to one `RUN` still does not work. I've tried several variations and still get either the secret key doesn't exist, that `--omit` is not a recognized command, etc. Honestly about to just use `ARG` at this point which I know is not recommended give `docker history <image>` but the `test` stage is not pushed to a container registry ever. It just runs in the CI and is destroyed. But it at least works for getting the stage running.

Comment: Please see my edit, i've been able to make it works with a simple Dockerfile and python script.

Comment: Thanks, testing it out now. Suggestions for how to get multiple secrets in there?

Comment: @cjones, for your build `--secret id=mysecret,src=mysecret.txt --secret id=another,src=another.txt`. 
Regarding dockerfile `RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret \
  --mount=type=secret,id=another \
  MYSECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/mysecret) \
  && export MYSECRET \
  && ANOTHER=$(cat /run/secrets/another) \
  && export ANOTHER \
  && python /tmp/test.py`

Comment: @cjones multiple secrets in one file can be like this:

Comment: Docker documentation has moved. It's here now: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypesecret